# How do I name the processes in a multiprocessing.pool?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

If I create a pool with 4 workers and set them to do some task (using `pool.apply_async(..)`), I can access the name of each process from within using `multiprocessing.current_process().name`, but how do I set the name from the parent process (this is mostly for logging)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Process.name` is [just a setter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/01b7d5898262dbe0e9edb321b3be9a34da196f6f/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L184), you can freely assign to it.

The Pool takes an [`initializer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool) argument. This can be any callable, and it'll be called once when each subprocess starts up. You can point this to a function that sets the `name` property of that process to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'm using initializer + setproctitle.

Comment: @TkTech @Sveltely @alasar in a function that I use as **initializer** for pool i set the name of the process using `multiprocessing.current_process().name = 'some string'` and use log record attribute **%(processName)s** in logging formatter, but still in log messages i see the default names created for the processes (Ex. PoolWorker-1, PoolWorker-2) and not the name that I am setting for the process in the initializer function. Could you please tell what's wrong.

Comment: @RajasiKulkarni You should ask a new question.

Comment: would the string for the name be reflected in the subprocess identify found in a call to pstree?